# RGB values varying with array values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, rgb, yuv

I have a project in which I am using d3js.I have to plot a line.But the twist is the color of line will vary with every array value(every 20px of line holds one element of following array).I have created lines but, I am facing problems with the colour intensity.I thought about for loops,but I am not getting exact results.I think I am not able to swith from one colour to another.

*(for example--from dim red-->light red-->little dark red-->dark red)*

I have a json with over 10k values.I have simplified my arrays for understanding purpose.

var array_1=[0.0,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9]

var array_2=[0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.09]

var array_3=[0.001,0.002,0.004,0.007,0.008]

**MyQuestion**:For any given color(red,blue,green,yellow etc etc),I should be able to plot the according to these array values in such a way that **Greater the number will be,Intense the color will be**.

Is it possible to create an algorithm that can manipulate the RGB values of any colour with array values that are numeric?If possible,it will be very kind of you to give some sample.

Comment: Well convert the RGB value to [HSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSI_color_space), increase the intensity component according to your value and convert the result back to RGB.

Comment: @Esailija:can you give me some link or info??the below given answers arent much helpful

Comment: @MESSIAH added an example at my answer , if it's not what you looking for I'll try another color transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to convert from YCbCr (YUV) to RGB since
the Y in YUV is luminescence it's as modifying the intensity of the color.

The formulas can be found on wikipedia here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr

There is also an example of this implemented in JavaScript here:
http://www.mikekohn.net/file_formats/yuv_rgb_converter.php

For example on Micael Kohn's page you can try setting a color in RGB
and covert it to YUV. After that just lower or raise the Y value and
convert it to RGB. You will notice that it's like changing the
intensity.

**EDIT:**

Here you go, wrote an example for you, just click on the div

```
function yuv2rgb(Y,U,V){
    R = Y + 1.4075 * (V - 128)
    G = Y - 0.3455 * (U - 128) - (0.7169 * (V - 128))
    B = Y + 1.7790 * (U - 128)
    return { r:Math.floor(R) , g:Math.floor(G) , b:Math.floor(B)}
}

function rgb2yuv(R,G,B){
    Y = R *  0.299000 + G *  0.587000 + B *  0.114000
    U = R * -0.168736 + G * -0.331264 + B *  0.500000 + 128
    V = R *  0.500000 + G * -0.418688 + B * -.081312 + 128
    return { y:Math.floor(Y) , u:Math.floor(U) , v:Math.floor(V)}
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b3FCK/

Comment: And where do you get all these values(128,0.29900 etc etc).Is it some kind of formula?

Comment: Yes,  if u read the article from that site.,  he gives a link to the formula.  The formula is also on wiki in matrix form

Comment: I was trying to search the difference between RGB and YUV,But I am still a little vague about it. Why there is a need of conversion,can RGB values be directly switched from one color to ligther or darker version of it

Comment: The problem is if you want to get a color lighter or darker in RGB you must modify each value related to all other values. Example red(150,0,0) you would god +(10,0,0) -(10,0,0) to change this color but for a gray (150,150,150) you should +(10,10,10) -(10,10,10) . Thus changing the R value for example is proportional with R G and B , that's why you need the YUV formula anyway

Comment: :I tried varying rgb,the problem i got was as I changed the parameters,I totally switched the colour!!!YUV will keep me in a particular domain.(i.e variance in red color only)
Thanks for the answer!!!